# put comma as separator in export to CSV in php

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I have to get mysql data in a CSV file on click of download button. The below code exports data successfully but adds space as separator. But I need comma to be separator not space, As there are space in mysql data and also on static header of csv file.

HTML code is below.

```
<form name="downloadform" id="downloadform" action="exportcsv.php" method="POST"> 
<div style="font-weight:bold; line-height:30px;" class="TableContainer">
        <label>Download CSV Format:</label>
        <button class="blue" name="btnDwld" id="btnDwld" type="submit">Download</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And export to csv code is below.

```
<?php 
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btnDwld']))
{
    $filname = "UploadRateWeight-".date("d-M-Y-H:i:s");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filname.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

    function echocsv($fields)
{
    $separator = ',';
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
           if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
                   $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
              } // end if
           echo $field.$separator;
        }   // end foreach
    echo "\r\n";
}

    $content = '';
    $title = '';
    $title = array('0'=>'head part1','1'=>'head part2','2'=>'head part3','3'=>'head part4','4'=>'head part5');
    $headerr = echocsv($title);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name = $rs["name"];
        $line = array('0'=>$name,'1'=>'','2'=>'','3'=>'','4'=>'');
        echocsv($line);
        //$content .= "\n";
    }
}
```

The out put in a .CSV file looks like below.

```
head
----------
name1
name2
name3
```

As you can see I have put 1st colum name as 'head part1' but it will show like 'head' as its taking space as separator.

So second column name takes this.

```
part1,head
----------
```

and third column name takes this.

```
part2,head
----------
```

and so on. So how to use a comma to be separator while exporting CSV file in php ??

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, the function `fputcsv` has existed forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write csv file's manually. Use the built in function.

e.g. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

```
<?php

$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, $delimiter, $enclosure);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

The above code will create a file called `file.csv` with your data on it. If you then want to send this file to the user as a CSV file, you can do this:

```
<?php

// Send the generated csv file to the browser as a download
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile('file.csv');

?>
```

Alternatively, you can send the CSV file to download directly without creating the file on server like this:

```
<?php

// mini-config
$delimiter = ',';

// Your data
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

// Send headers
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// Output csv data
foreach ($list as $row) {
    echo implode($delimiter, $row) . "\r\n";
}

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes. I have seen this function here in SO. but I am confused that    'fopen()'  will open a file or create a file ? I want to create a file on click of download with the data in it.

Comment: Apologies, I thought are trying to create the file. See updated answer.

Comment: No, The last block of your answer, which I need, CSV file to download directly without creating the file is not working. You can also check this. Just edit your array and put space in to the values. Just like 'aa a', 'b bb', 'cc cc'. You can see, its not working.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? See this http://i.imgur.com/XbW8Y6C.png and http://i.imgur.com/XmZdjQT.png

Comment: If you need to write directly to the output, `fopen('php://output', 'w')`. Still no need to do manual delimiting.