# change separator "," in ";" from Mysqli in .csv

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

This code export one file.csv and separated the columns with ","

I have another little problem with this code. Regional settings of my PC are not on the US but on Romanian. This means that with the US separation is done by "," and in Romanian by ";" and Excel takes regional settings of the PC.
What can I do to code to make separation by ";" ?
Thank you!

```html
<?php

// call export function
exportMysqlToCsv('export_csv.csv');


// export csv
function exportMysqlToCsv($filename = 'export_csv.csv')
{

   $conn = dbConnection();
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql_query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = $conn->query($sql_query);

    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
    $first = true;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($first) {
            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
            $first = false;
        }
        fputcsv($f, $row);
    } // end while

    $conn->close();

    $size = ftell($f);
    rewind($f);

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    fpassthru($f);
    exit;

}

// db connection function
function dbConnection(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDB";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    return $conn;
}


?>
```

Comment: you know you can add a delimiter to the `fputcsv`?

Comment: I don't know add delimiter

Comment: The syntax according to PHP docs is: `int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )`

So, choose an optional delimiter:
`fputcsv($f, $row,';');`

Comment: Thank you Tom Lankhorst, the cod function perfect. What can I do if the code runs on PCs with different regional settings?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like below, you can refer [put comma as separator in export to CSV in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527678/put-comma-as-separator-in-export-to-csv-in-php) for more.

```
$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';

$f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
$first = true;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($f, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
}
```

Comment: I changed my while with your while and export everything in a column

Comment: @StericaSt So now what is the issue?

Comment: result it's the same

Comment: @StericaSt Have you changed the delimiter sign as you want to get, then check?

Comment: I changed delimiter and function, put not type header. I can get them to recognize the code automatically regional settings?

Comment: @KaushaMehtra: I did some tests in the link above, but it is difficult for me to choose only what is necessary link. I have advanced knowledge of php.